# Reinstalling Ubuntu without ereasing other partitions

Tags: partitioning, reinstall

I already have Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. It is in a disk partitioned with Windows 10 ( With windows boot manager and UEFI). I also have a ext4 partition just for files, obviously only avialble in ubuntu.

Recently I have been experienced problems with Ubuntu so I decide to reinstall it. I don't want to erase the other partitions.

Trough the Installation I have two main options (clearly I do not want to erase the disk) the first one and the last one  like the picture below: [image]

When I choose  the first one it show me the next dialog:
[image]

And when I choose the last one it show me this:
[image]

I am not an expert so I want to avoid the last option. 
My question **it is safe if I proceed with the first one?** Or it will erased the other partitions.

EDIT 1:

The partition with the /root is in partition 7.

Comment: The first option is more automated and you can't be sure what partition might be deleted on installation. You haven't said which partition Ubuntu is already installed on. I assume it's sda7 but you need to be sure. Choose 'Something Else' and install on the appropriate partition. I'd re-format it ext4. Just to be safe, back-up your data before you start.

Comment: @PaulBenson It is in dev sda7. If I choose "Something Else" and re-format sda7 as ext4 and install ubuntu there, what I have to choose in: Device for boot loader installation? and what about the swap? I should erease the current one and create another for this new installation? or the old one will work?. I need to be sure that doesn't ereased important things because I cannot back-up my data.

Comment: You don 't have to worry about 'swap'. 18.04 comes with its own `/swapfile`. As you have sda2 as your 'efi' partition that is your boot partition. If you can boot into either system with Grub, leave it alone, but back up your `/boot` folder. As you will be installing Ubuntu after Windows you may find that you can't boot into Windows  as Grub is re-written. If so that can be fixed.

Comment: @PaulBenson Yes I have a dual boot. So from the last picture I just have to click Install Now?

Comment: As long as you've done what I suggested and chosen sda7 as your partition for 'Root' then go ahead.

Comment: @PaulBenson when I tried back-up my boot folder the system show me the message: ' The folder "efi" cannot be handled because you do not have permision to read it' some help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99351/discussion-between-paul-benson-and-jose-marin).

Comment: Sorry, the chatroom won't let me post anything so we'll continue here. You need to prefix command with `sudo`, eg `sudo cp. . .` as you need superuser permissions. Don't copy to that partition as you're about to delete everything there. Use a USB drive.

Comment: @PaulBenson Ok. Don't worry, I think I can handle by now. Thank you.

Comment: OK. Let me know if you have a problem with grub or booting into Windows afterwards.

Comment: @PaulBenson Sure. So at the option: Device for boot loader installation I should change the current option: /dev/sda ATA WDC WD10JPVX-22J(1.0 TB) to /dev/sda2 efi?

Comment: I don't remember being asked for a boot option when installing 18.04. Can you not ignore it? What are the other options?

Comment: @PaulBenson The other options are the other partitions.

Comment: Yeah. Choose sda2!

Comment: @PaulBenson I see, well, this will take me some time. I am trying to repair some issues in my ubuntu also. So if I cannot achieve that I will reinstall the OS. well, I'll keep you up to date. Thanks.

Comment: @PaulBenson At the end ( after spending all the afternoon) I can solve some of the main issues I was having with Ubuntu so at the end I decline (for now ) to reinstall it. Thank you for your support.